# VBA copying cell dependent on text to next blank cell on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I created the below and i'm an absolute noob, i literally just pieced different bits of info together to get it working and it did, until i added the selecting the cell if it has 'r' in it and moving it to 'sheet7' and now i get an (object required) error when it runs.

I really need some help on this and if you are feeling generous, i would like to repeat the exercise with several other letters and sheets, so if you could demonstrate an additional one too, i'm sure i could work out the rest.

Thanks in advance

```css
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("I16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J20").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
    Range("I16").Select
        If Cell.Value = "R" Then
    Range("J20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet7").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when writing macros it's good practice to avoid selecting cells. Selecting a cell is really something that only a human does, but in VBA we can just refer to the cell directly without touching it.

Rewriting your macro to avoid all the touching:

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Make a variable to store the cell found
    Dim lastCell as Range

    'find the last cell in Column A of the active sheet
    lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Paste in the I16 value
    lastCell.value = RangE("I16").value

    'Grab whatever is hanging out in Column B next to the last cell and stick it in J20
    Range("J20").value = lastCell.Offset(0,1).value 

    'Test to see if I16 has value "R"
    If Range("I16").value = "R" Then

        'Find the last row in Sheet7, Column B and store it to the variable
        lastCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        'Copy J20 value to the lastCell in Sheet 7, Column B
        lastCell = Range("J20").value
    End if


End Sub
```

I'm not sure where you were getting the error you reported. It's probably specific to your workbook, so we'd have to be sitting in front of it to track it down. This rewrite may correct it though.

Also, it's not clear what else is happening in this process. My guess is that Column B of the Active Sheet has a formula in it that does something to the value we paste from `I16`. After it's pasted and calculated we grab that and stick it in `J20` and if `I16` is equal to `"R"` then we put that calculated `J20` value over `Sheet7`. If that sounds about right, then the macro above should do the trick.

Also, if that IS what's happening, then perhaps you could share the formula you have in Column B. We can probable to do that calculation within VBA and save a ton of steps in this macro.

Comment: Hi thanks for the swift response!

I have tried your code and unfortunately got a syntax error on

' If Range("I16").value = "R" '

and yes you are right, i have a formula in B -
' =IF(LEN(A1)=0, "", A1&ROW()+15999) '

That was so that when i press the button is produces the next number in the sequence with the chosen letter as a prefix, it just used the row number to get it

Comment: Oh! shoot. YEa sorry I forgot the `Then` in that line: `If Range("I16").value = "R" Then` I wrote it in Notepad real quick and didn't double check it.

Comment: That makes sense for your formula. In that case, it might make sense just to leave it as-is and rely on the formula to generate the row id that you bring into Sheet7. That makes sense.

Comment: JNevill, thanks for all your help so far it's much appreciated. unfortunately it's still not working for me. It's now throwing back an error  - object variable or with block variable not set    that is against line 'lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)'