# Excel VBA - Error in code to copy to specific sheet, dependent on range

Tags: vba, excel

JNevill very kindly cleaned up and improved the macro i had put together, unfortunately its coming back with errors and i havent been able to get a response to the original post. Hopefully someone can pick up where he left off.

the fault i'm getting is - object variable or with block variable not set that is against line `lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

```
Sub Macro1()
'Make a variable to store the cell found
Dim lastCell as Range

'find the last cell in Column A of the active sheet
lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

'Paste in the I16 value
lastCell.value = RangE("I16").value

'Grab whatever is hanging out in Column B next to the last cell and stick it in J20
Range("J20").value = lastCell.Offset(0,1).value 

'Test to see if I16 has value "R"
If Range("I16").value = "R" Then

    'Find the last row in Sheet7, Column B and store it to the variable
    lastCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Copy J20 value to the lastCell in Sheet 7, Column B
    lastCell = Range("J20").value
End if


End Sub
```

original post is here  [ORIGINAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731265/vba-copying-cell-dependent-on-text-to-next-blank-cell-on-another-worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing `Set` (since it's an object variable):

```
Set lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Based on comments below, I think this is the sort of thing you want:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    'Make a variable to store the cell found
    Dim lastCell              As Range

    'find the last cell in Column A of the active sheet
    Set lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Paste in the I16 value
    lastCell.Value = Range("I16").Value

    'Grab whatever is hanging out in Column B next to the last cell and stick it in J20
    Range("J20").Value = lastCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    'Test to see if I16 has value "R"
    Select Case VBA.UCase$(Range("I16").Value2)
        Case "R"
            Set ws = sheet7
        Case "C"
            Set ws = sheet3
        Case "P"
            Set ws = Sheet1
        Case "S"
            Set ws = Sheet2
    End Select

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        'Find the last row in Sheet7, Column B and store it to the variable
        Set lastCell = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        'Copy J20 value to the lastCell in Sheet 7, Column B
        lastCell = Range("J20").Value
        Application.Goto lastCell, True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, its stopped the fault, but it still not pasting it onto sheet7

Comment: also, if you don't mind, it has a few sheets it could go to dependent on which letter is used
{c} = sheet3
{P} = sheet1
{S} = sheet2

if you could get that into the bind as well, id be most gratefull

Comment: You don't refer to Sheet7 anywhere in this code, so all `Range` calls are defaulting to either the active sheet (if the code is in a normal module) or the worksheet containing the code.

Comment: i thought that might have been the case....any chance you might be able to assist? i have absolutely no idea, i literally just pieced together the mess i came up with originally

Comment: @BrianBennett I've updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Awesome work Rory, you have done me a huge favour!! thanks alot

could i be really cheeky and ask for one last thing?

Comment: is there a way to make it not only post the number on the sheet, but also take you there, so you literally press the macro button and then you are on the page you need with you're newly generate number

Comment: @BrianBennett Probably - everybody does... :) I've added a line.